# PHP: duplicate value removal

Tags: php, arrays, pchart

I have 2 arrays with for example 1000 key's each, one holds a temperature value and the other the hour.

Example array temp:

```
[0] = 3.1
[1] = 4.3
[2] = 4.1
[3] = 5.1
[4] = 4.1
```

Example hour array:

```
[0] = 0
[1] = 1
[2] = 2
[3] = 3
[4] = 3
```

The problem with this is that when i combine these to arrays and plot this in for example pchart i have too many values on the X and it gets cluttered.
So what i need to to remove the duplicate hours and replace then with "NULL", so that the unneeded hours are not plotted on the x axis.
I want to keep the first hour in the array, the second to the end of the duplicates can be set to "NULL"

The hour output array should be:

```
[0] = 0
[1] = 1
[2] = 2
[3] = 3
[4] = NULL
etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is sorted, so... how about this?

```
$hours = array(0,1,2,3,3,4,4,5);
$prev = -1;
foreach ($hours as &$hour) {
  if ($prev === $hour) {
    $hour = NULL;
  }
  else {
    $prev = $hour;
  }
}
unset($hour);
print_r($hours); // 0,1,2,3,NULL,4,NULL,5...
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a job for [`array_unique()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

> ```
> array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
> ```
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.
>
> Note that keys are preserved. array_unique() sorts the values treated
>   as string at first, then will keep the first key encountered for every
>   value, and ignore all following keys. It does not mean that the key of
>   the first related value from the unsorted array will be kept.
>
> > **Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1
> >     === (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the same. The first element will be used.**

---

If you require the array keys to persist, you can try something with `array_map()`.

```
<?php

//Variable initialization
$array = array(
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 3,
    4 => 3
);
$temp  = array();

$array = array_map(function($element) use (&$temp) {
    if (!in_array($element, $temp)) {
        $temp[] = $element;
        return $element;
    }
    return null;
}, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Could be, but i need to keep the same amount of keys in both of the arrays. The duplicate keys in the hour array need to be set to NULL, not deleted..

Comment: @HyperDevil: Edited my answer. Will try to figure out a better way than globals.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php 5.3:

```
$a = array(0,1,2,3,4,4,5);

array_walk($a, function(&$item) {
  static $encountered = array();
  if(in_array($item, $encountered)) {
    $item = null;
    return;
  }
  $encountered[] = $item;
});

var_dump($a);
```

Will preserve the number of keys. Array_walk calls a user function for every key. static makes it so that the $encountered array in the scope of the function stays between executions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the duplicates entirely you can use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) 
but it wont set them to NULL.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this trick does it:

```
$simplified = array_combine($hours, $temperatures);

$hours = array_keys($simplified);
$temperatures = array_values($simplified);
```

This won't set things to NULL but to completely remove them which I think is what you're looking for. Otherwise this should do it:

```
foreach(array_slice(array_reverse(array_keys($hours)), 0, -1) as $i)
    ($hours[$i] === $hours[$i-1]) && $hours[$i] = NULL;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/8ahi0OOo)

Comment: I'm not sure you really need. Try it out and report back (unless you don't test this, I won't trust you :) )

Comment: How is this better/different than using `array_unique()` on both?

Comment: @Truth: The relationship between both arrays is preserved (which seems to be necessary for a graph or plot).