# Pchart: X axis, too many ticks

Tags: php, pchart

I have quite a large dataset, about a 1000 values. (temperature graph)

[image: temperature graph]


As you can see i have too many ticks between the hours, i only want one tick per hour.
Now it's a very think black line, how can i fix this?

The x axis array is like this:
    [2] = 1
    [3] = NULL
    [4] = NULL
    [5] = 2
    [6] = NULL
    etc

Comment: @Salil Momin, thats all i use to make the linegraph.
Pchart library is available on the internet for free.

Comment: So `NULL`'ing didn't help ya? How come.... ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/q/10435986/367456

Comment: @HyperDevil: The picture is broken.

Comment: @hakre: yes the NULL now hides the X label so that is working fine, now i need to hide the small "tick line" for the values other then the hours..

Answer (score 2):

In the scale settings, you must set the LabelSkip.

```
$labelskip = 1000/24; // values = 1000, hours = 24
$scaleSettings = array("LabelSkip"=>$labelskip);    
$myPicture->drawScale($scaleSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was generated form `$MyData->setSerieTicks("Time",1000);` you have 2 lines in your chat cahnge it to `$MyData->setSerieTicks("Time",1);` you would see the difference

Comment: Hold on let me run it my self

Comment: Remember i have about a 1000 values, so i need to get rid of some x axis ticks, but not the values itself in the graph.

Comment: Just tested it 100 values and this not have such used exactly this code http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.chart.drawlinechart.html ... what version og pChart are u using

Comment: 2.13, can you try with a 1000?

Comment: has memory time out only used for($i = 0 ; $i < 200; $i++)
{
 $time[] = mt_rand(1,20);
 $temp[] = mt_rand(0, 10); 
}

Comment: you are connecting to a database and i don't have such datata