# pChart axis X gap in scale

Tags: php, pchart

I'm using the pChart library and I want to have a X scale of 1-100 but on the chart I want to have divisions in multiples of 10. I have 2000 data points.

Unfortunately my axis X is not readable, as the `|` is placed at every axis unit, rather than every 10. Now it looks like this - any ideas?

[image]

Edit: 
after using @EPICWebDesign tip i got 
[image]

How to remove duplicate `X` values. I can do `array_unique` but then i lose some points on chart.

Comment: The description isn't fully clear. Is the problem that you want to remove the vertical bars from the X axis?

Comment: Yes this is what im trying to achive

Answer (score 1):

#### First Answer

If this is pChart 2, you can use the LabelSkip setting.

ie: "LabelSkip"=>$X,

will make it show only each $X th label, while still showing all of the data points.

From the wiki: You can skip specified number of X labels using LabelSkip.
http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.doc.draw.scale.html

#### Second Answer

You can make the duplicate x axis values null. See [PHP: duplicate value removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435986/php-duplicate-value-removal)

Here is a more specific example:

```
$x = array(1,1,2,3,4,5);
$prev = -1;
foreach ($x as &$point) {
  if ($prev === $point) {
    $point= NULL;
  }
  else {
    $prev = $point;
  }
}
unset($point);
print_r($x); // 1,NULL,2,3,4,5...
```

Comment: I've edit my post could U anwser one more question, about axis X

Comment: Labelskip shouldn't change the data.. I notice the two graphs are very similar but not exactly the same. Are you able to post code?

As far as the 1 showing twice, it looks like it did on the first one too, but automatically skipped it there. on the second graph you manually set it to skip 10 spaces, so it showed 1 twice. 

What is this graph portraying?